# Method of finding roots of this equation

Tags: roots

I'm trying to find the roots $\omega_n$ of,
\begin{equation}
\tan(\omega) = \frac{2b\omega}{b^2\omega^2 -1}
\end{equation}

I know it must be done numerically, so I would use the bisection method.
In order to use that I must know the interval to search for each root for any $b \in (0,1)$.
The problem is that there is different behaviour of the singularities at $b>1/2$.
Does anyone know a way to solve the roots of this?

Comment: Have you plotted the functions?  Perhaps you can gain insights as to their respective characteristics.  Have you heard of Newton's method or the secant method?

Comment: Yes, I plotted and it can be seen here: https://postimg.org/image/f85kkxe8n/ The dashed lines are $b \in (1/2,1), solids are $b \in (0,1/2]$. Note where the singularities lie for them.

Comment: Which roots are you interested in? There are infinitely-many real roots. Could you also clarify what you mean by "there is different behavior of the singularities at $b > 1/2$"? I don't notice a difference between $b<1/2$ and $b>1/2$ in the plot you linked.

Comment: I would like to be able to find all up to an arbitrary $n$. The plot shows the first four roots. I'll clarify, @antonio-vargas. Except for the first three roots ($n=0,1,2$), the dashed lines ($b>1/2$) begin and end at $\pi/2 + n\pi$, sequential singularities of $\tan\omega$. For the solid ($b<1/2$) some lines begin and end at tan singularities and others asymptote to other intermediate points. Knowing the interval to search for a particular root is what I need for applying the bisection method.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to look for the zeros of function
$$f(\omega)=\left(b^2 \omega ^2-1\right) \sin (\omega )-2 b \,\omega\,  \cos (\omega )$$ which does not show any discontinuity.

Focusing on the first postive root, series expansion followed by power series reversion gives, as an approximation,
$$\omega=t+\frac {20 b^2+10 b+1}{40(6 b^2+6 b+1 ) }   t^3+$$ $$\frac {48720 b^4+45360 b^3+15300 b^2+2140 b+107}{67200(6 b^2+6 b+1 )^2}t^5+O(t^7)$$where
$$t=\sqrt{\frac{6 (2 b+1)}{6 b^2+6 b+1} }$$

As shown below, the approximation is decent (it could be improved at the price of more terms in the initial series expansion).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
b & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 & 2.69706 &  2.85774 \\
 0.10 & 2.49284 &  2.62768 \\
 0.15 & 2.32792 &  2.43990 \\
 0.20 & 2.19140 &  2.28445 \\
 0.25 & 2.07603 &  2.15375 \\
 0.30 & 1.97688 &  2.04223 \\
 0.35 & 1.89049 &  1.94582 \\
 0.40 & 1.81433 &  1.86151 \\
 0.45 & 1.74654 &  1.78704 \\
 0.50 & 1.68568 &  1.72067 \\
 0.55 & 1.63066 &  1.66106 \\
 0.60 & 1.58059 &  1.60715 \\
 0.65 & 1.53479 &  1.55811 \\
 0.70 & 1.49267 &  1.51325 \\
 0.75 & 1.45378 &  1.47201 \\
 0.80 & 1.41772 &  1.43394 \\
 0.85 & 1.38417 &  1.39866 \\
 0.90 & 1.35285 &  1.36584 \\
 0.95 & 1.32353 &  1.33521 \\
 1.00 & 1.29600 &  1.30654 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

In any manner, with these estimates, Newton method converges in a couple of iterattions.